# Session variable not storing for Chrome/Android

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, session-variables

So have this "bug". We have a web app - MVC/.net (4.6) hosted on Azure on a single server. We do something on the client side, submit it and store a value temporarily in session on the server side.  When we go back to check this value it is fine on almost every browser/platform.

But not on Chrome/Android. When we submit on chrome/android, store the value and go back and check it, it has not stored. Other session variables have. We have checked this on Chrome/Windows/Mac, FF windows/mac, FF/Android, Samsung Browser/Android and all work fine.

Just not Chrome/Android. Just can't figure this out. Suspect it's something to do with Azure/cookies but we've just hit a dead end on it.

Comment: What do you mean by go back and check it? and do you have any code?

Comment: the usual "stick a variable in session" and go back and retrieve it. Session["test"] = 1... var test  = Session["test"].. var  test = null when you retrieve it (but only on Chrome/Android